# Regular expression from 00001 to 99999

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex and I want the number from `00001` to `99999`. It should have 5 digits.

I know I can use `[0-9]{5}`, but then I have the number `00000`, but it should begin at `00001`.

Comment: `[0-9]{4}[1-9]`?

Comment: @Maroun what about `10000`?

Comment: Maybe regex isn't the best solution for this? If you convert to an actual number, you can just check whether it's `>= 1` and `<= 99999`. Also note that `[0-9]` is generally written `\d`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, misunderstood OP's question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?!00000)[0-9]{5}
```

Prefixing `(?!00000)` ensures you don't match it; it's called negative lookahead.
Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/3D2Knn/1).

Comment: Will it match `1` ?

Comment: If it suits you and it comes in time before similar answers, you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This rather ugly regexp requires that at least one of the 5 digits is not a zero. Therefore, the only 5 digit number that fails is 00000. But I think there must be a more elegant way.

`^([1-9]\d{4}|\d[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{3}[1-9]\d|\d{4}[1-9])$`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!00000)[0-9]{5}
```

Explanation:

- Negative Lookahead (?!00000) - Assert that the Regex does not match it
- [0-9] a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- {5} Matches exactly 5 times

Comment: Thanks you very much, this works! And thanks for the explanation